# Jabber Openfire server v3.6.0a+ - how do I use Hybrid authentication?

Tags: configuration, xmpp, openfire

I'm setting up a Jabber server for my website.  I've already got some user accounts in place in the openfire database, and working IMs between them.

I'm now looking to add (some) of the users from my main database (`members` table, with `login`, `password`[plain text]) and `allowed_to_IM`[0 or 1] fields) to allow them to communicate between themselves.  The `Hybrid` authentication is a new feature in v3.6.0a however, and there's little documentation in what configuration is required in the `openfire.xml` file for the database connectivity (to a second database), and what else may go in the properties (which have also taken much of the config's info away of the XML file).

My question is: *Does anyone have a complete example that checks multiple databases?* All the examples I'm seen seem to be just fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it using ldap and mysql and if it helps you my setting from openfire.xml are:

```
    <connectionProvider>
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className>
  </connectionProvider>
  <database>
    <defaultProvider>
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
      <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/openfire</serverURL>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>pass</password>
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>
      <maxConnections>15</maxConnections>
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout>
    </defaultProvider>
  </database>
  <ldap>
  ldapsetting removed
  </ldap>
  <hybridAuthProvider>
    <primaryProvider>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthProvider</className>
    </primaryProvider>
    <secondaryProvider>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapAuthProvider</className>
    </secondaryProvider>
  </hybridAuthProvider>
  <provider>
    <auth>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.HybridAuthProvider</className>
    </auth>
    <vcard>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthProvider</className>
    </vcard>
    <user>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapUserProvider</className>
    </user>
    <auth>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapAuthProvider</className>
    </auth>
    <group>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.ldap.LdapGroupProvider</className>
    </group>
  </provider>
```