# Jabber Openfire server v3.6.0a+ - how do I use Hybrid authentication?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I've got pretty much the same question as: [Jabber Openfire server v3.6.0a+ - how do I use Hybrid authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364/jabber-openfire-server-v360a-how-do-i-use-hybrid-authentication)

But when I followed the instructions there, and I go into the Admin interface > Users and Groups > Create New User, I get the following message:

```
Not allowed: the user account system is read-only.
```

That tells me that the system is trying to add to the LDAP structure, and not to the database.  Does anyone have a working config that allows both LDAP and Database users to login, and to be able to create Database Users?

I believe in the latest version of Openfire, settings are pulled from the database but not the openfire.xml file.  Unfortunately, there's little documentation on their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... so I have been looking for how to do this for 6 months now.  And not more than 15 mins after I post this question, I find the link here:
http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/204225

Also, the settings are now saved in the databsae, so the openfire.xml is irrelevant for these settings.